# sending image as byte array from matlab to java through sockets

Tags: matlab

I am trying to send images from a matlab server to a java client through a sockets. First I converted the image to a byte array and I used the readFully method on the client side which requires a length to be specified.
The problem is that the size of the byte array changes from one image to the other and when I send the size through the write () method it does not read correctly on the client side.
Here is a snippet of my code

Matlab server

```
%% convert image 
Javaimage=im2java2d (image);
Arraystream=ByteArrayOutputStream;
ImageIO.write (javaimage,'jpg', arraystream)
Arraystream.flush ();
Bytearray=arraystream.toByteArray;

%% send size through output stream
Outstream=write (size (byteArray, 1))
%% send array
outStream=write (byteArray);
```

On the client side I have tried many methods such as read, readInt, readDouble, but I think the trouble is the write () method I tried to use writeInt ()  but matlab did not recognize it even though I included the libraries needed: 
    Java.io
    Java.net
    Java.io.dataoutputstream
    Java.io.datainputstream

I should also include that the size of the array is usually over 10000
I would appreciate any help 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Arraystream=ByteArrayOutputStream;
Undefined function or variable 'ByteArrayOutputStream'. Can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @user1850484 , I'd really like to help you. can you clarify a bit more by showing code?? Maybe you did'nt import the needed Java libraries.

Comment: I have  already solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the answer which is so simple that it was the last thing to check.

When I created the socket input and output streams I did the following

```
     InStream =socket.getInputStream; 
     OutStream=socket.getOutputStream;
```

This allows you to use the methods from the inputStream class such as read () and write() which are methods that only read bytes.To read any other types of data we must use the dataInputStream and dataOutput stream classes which are a type of filter class that allow reading primitive types such as int , double , etc using methods such as readInt () and writeInt
To do this you need to change the above as follows

```
 Instream=dataInputStream (socket.getInputStream); 
 OutStream=dataOutputStream (socket.getOutputStream);
```

And its that simple.